# Laravel Middleware Executing in Incorrect Order

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have a Middleware for ajax-only routes.

```
// AjaxOnly Middleware class
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!$request->ajax()) {
        // dd('I\'m (condition) working as expected!');
        return response()->view('layouts.app');
    }

    dd('I never work!');

    return $next($request);
}
```

Here is my routes web.php

```
// Ajax only routes
Route::group(['middleware' => 'ajaxOnly'], function () {

    // Work an print 'false'
    // dd(Request::ajax());

    // Redirect me to /login page
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:user']], function () {

        Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    });

    // Authentication routes
    Auth::routes();
});
```

So, can someone explain why the code continues to run inside Middleware-protected closure? Thanks.

UPD: Just clarify -

1. Expected behavior: layouts.app in my browser.
2. Real behavior: redirect to login page.

Comment: Did you mistype !$request->ajax() ? The ! will do the opposite. So if it's not ajax you'll get the response()->view()

Comment: Hmm, can you explain what do you mean, by "continues to run"? How are you accessing it, what do you get and what is the desired result? @NMahurin That part makes sense, you don't want to return a view on ajax request usually.

Comment: Hmm, I think I was thrown off by the dd(I'm working as expected) part, like that's where it was supposed to go if it's an ajax request.

Comment: @NMahurin It's expected behavior. If request NOT ajax -> just return view. `dd(I'm working as expected)` means my condition `if (!$request->ajax())` works good for non ajax request. But with commented line it redirect me to /login page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust your middleware priority to ensure the correct middleware executes in the correct order. You can achieve this by overriding the default `$middlewarePriority` in your `Kernel.php` file.

```
/**
 * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
 *
 * Forces the listed middleware to always be in the given order.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \Illuminate\xxx\Middleware\AjaxOnly::class,
    \Illuminate\xxx\Middleware\Auth::class,
];
```

You can follow what `Illuminate\Routing\Router` does with `$middlewarePriorty` [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L651) in the source code.